# How can i add request id to nginx error log?

Tags: nginx

I want to add request id which generated by nginx to nginx error log.

Example nginx access log:

> 200 [27/Sep/2021:12:12:39 +0300] ..101.24-- ..101.24 GET /?fname=%22+or+%22%22%3D%22&lname= HTTP/1.1 - Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 **c85f0187b2cf1b15c24b6133b671f431

Is it possible also in error log?

Comment: You cannot customize error log contents. Also, I don't think that request ID is generated by nginx.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen As far as I can remember (I'm not sure) that number being logged in the nginx error log is a nginx worker ID.

Comment: Although nginx error log cannot be customized , nginx c code may be changed to do this.